# Rendering D3 data from CSV

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

This is more of a request for a code review, but I cannot for the life of me get this `.csv` data to render properly as a line-chart in D3...

Below is the code I've written.

So far, I've only been able to render the y-axis and the axis title, but I can't seem to render the data. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but simply can't see it.

Help and advice is hugely appreciated.

### JavaScript File

```
// ./weather-app/d3/testing-dsky-d3.js
const fname_forecast =  'forecast-hourly-temp.csv';
const path2File = './csv/';

const parseDateTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

d3.csv(path2File + fname_forecast)
  .row((data) => {
    return {
      date: parseDateTime(data.datetime),
      temp: +data.temperature
    }
  })
  .get((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('\nErrors!\n', err)
    } else {
      console.log(data);

      const minDate = d3.min(data, (d) => { return d.date; });
      const maxDate = d3.max(data, (d) => { return d.date; });

      const minTemp = d3.min(data, (d) => { return d.temp; });
      const maxTemp = d3.max(data, (d) => { return d.temp; });

      const svg = d3.select('svg'),
            margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            g = svg.append('g')
                      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left +   ',' + margin.top + ')');

      const x = d3.scaleTime()
                  .rangeRound([minDate, maxDate])
                  .domain([minDate, maxDate]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .rangeRound([height, 0])
                  .domain([height, 0])

      const line = d3.line()
                     .x((d) => { return x(d.date); })
                     .y((d) => { return y(d.temp); });

      g.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .select('.domain')
          .remove();

      g.append('g')
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append('text')
          .attr('fill', '#000')
          .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
          .attr('y', 6)
          .attr('dy', '0.71em')
          .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
          .text('Temperature (degC)');

      g.append('path')
          .datum(data)
          .attr('fill', 'none')
          .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
          .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
          .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
          .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
          .attr('d', line);

       }
     });
```

### The HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Test: Rendering DarkSky Data w/ D3</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='./learn/d3.v4.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Test: Rendering DarkSky API Temperature Data w/   <code>D3.js</code></h1>
  <hr><br>
  <div id='container'>
    <svg width='960' height='500'></svg>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='testing-dsky-d3.js'></script>

</body>
```

### And then some sample `.csv` file

```
datetime,temperature

2018-04-04 12:00:00,46.98

2018-04-04 13:00:00,48.43

2018-04-04 14:00:00,49.63

2018-04-04 15:00:00,49.85

2018-04-04 16:00:00,48.98

2018-04-04 17:00:00,47.95

2018-04-04 18:00:00,47.35

2018-04-04 19:00:00,47.08

2018-04-04 20:00:00,46.79

2018-04-04 21:00:00,46.62
```

Comment: Hi can you rework this into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Does jsfiddle.net support D3, and would I be able to load in external csv files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your scales' domains and ranges properly,

Here:

```
 const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([minDate, maxDate])
    .domain([minDate, maxDate]);
```

You are setting a scale to take values from minDate to maxDate (the domain) and map them to values from minDate to maxDate (the range). You need to modify this:

```
 const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0,width])       // values to map to (x coordinate values)
    .domain([minDate, maxDate]); // extent of input values/values needing scaling
```

Same for your y axis:

```
  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
              .rangeRound([height, 0])
              .domain([height, 0])
```

You need to differentiate your range and domain. The scale above simply takes a value between 0 and `height` and returns the same value.

---

To fix your graph you need to properly set:

- Domain to an extent of input values in your dataset (temp,date,etc)
- Range to an extent of output values, usually coordinate values for x or y (or color, radius, etc).

Applying these changes (I hard coded a domain of [40,50] for temperature) like so:

```
  const x = d3.scaleTime()
              .rangeRound([0,width])
              .domain([minDate, maxDate]);
  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([40, 50])
              .rangeRound([height, 0])
```

and otherwise using your code and data, I get:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your tips and advice!  I'll play around with the code. :)

Comment: Okay!  I've changed the code and got a static HTML page working,

Comment: And everything is looking ok?

Comment: It is indeed!  Many thanks!  I read over your suggestions and referred back to an example from M.Bostock, and rewrote the JS in the <script> elements.

My issue now, is that I want to serve up this static d3.html page through a Flask endpoint, but unfortunately, the figure is not rendering when i make the call to `render_template('d3.html')`.

Comment: Here's the link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682823/serving-a-static-d3-html-file-on-flask-endpoint

Comment: I added a flask tag to your new question, as that might help find a solution, might be a routing issue to the dependencies?

Comment: Okay!  I've got it!